# Whats the correct syntax to increment a sequence?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a function that looks like this.

```
    Function GetNewBatch ( CourseName Varchar2 ) Return RefCursor
    As
      Results RefCursor;
      CourseId Number;
    Begin

      CourseId := Courselist.GetId( CourseName );

      Open    Results For 
      Select  q.user_abn           UserAbn,
              q.completed_t        DateCompleted,
                                   CourseName,
              q.batch_n            BatchId
      From    GAK.GAKHR02_ACK q
      Where   q.crse_i  = CourseId
      And     q.batch_n is null
      And     rownum < 1000;

      GAK.SEQ1_GAKHR03.NextVal;
      Return Results;
    End;
```

I want to increment the sequence after the select, but SQL Developer is giving me the error:

"Error(194,5): PLS-00313: 'NEXTVAL' not declared in this scope."

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you're not assigning the `nextval` to a variable. *Assume* that `.nextval` is a function of some description. It's not, Oracle actually describe it as a psuedocolumn; something used in the same context as a column but not written to the disk.

How you [increment a sequence](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/views002.htm#ADMIN11796) depends on the version of Oracle you're using. Prior to 11G you could do the following in a PL/SQL block:

```
declare    
   i number;    
begin

   select my_sequence.nextval
     into i
     from dual;

   insert into my_table(id)
   values(my_sequence.nextval);

   update my_table
      set id = my_sequence.nextval;

end;
```

In 11G this changed slightly so you could also assign the "return" value from `.nextval` to a variable:

```
declare
   l_next_val number;
begin
   l_next_val := my_sequence.nextval;
end;
```

The reason for PLS-00313 is that Oracle is assuming that `SEQ1_GAKHR03` is a package or some other object and `.nextval` is a sub-type of this object.

It's very unusual to increment a sequence without actually using the value. Is this intended behaviour?

Comment: Yes, this is the intended behavior.  We only want to increment the sequence after we process x number of records.  It won't be used until the next time we process a set, where that value is assigned.

And I'm fully aware that the name isn't descriptive, but thats the naming convention that I have to use.

Comment: Which actually leads me to a new question, how can I assign a value to BatchId for each record that is in the RefCursor?

Comment: 2 options: Use the psuedo-column `rownum`, which will give you a unique identifier. Or use an analytic function, such as `rank() over ( partition by batch )`, which'll give you a distinct number per batch.